# How to save formsets in django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I want to add multiple forms when a button is clicked and I am using formsets to accomplish that but when I try to save the forms it doesn't give an error bu does not save it either.

my views.py:

```py
def StepThreeView(request):
    formSet = modelformset_factory(Club, fields=("name", "channel", "logo", "created_by"))

    form = formSet(queryset=Example.objects.none())

    if (request.method == "POST"):
        form = formSet(request.POST)

        if (form.is_valid()):
            form.save()

    context = {
        'form': form
    }

    return render(request, 'on_boarding/step_three.html', context)
```

my html:

```html
<form method="POST" id="form">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.management_form }}
      <div class="hidden" id="form-copy">
         {{ form.empty_form.as_p }}
     </div>
</form>

<button class="add-club" type="button" onclick="AddUser()">
    Add user
</button>
```

my javascript:

```js
function AddUser() {
    const formCopyTarget = document.getElementById("formCopyTarget");
    const copyForm = document.getElementById("form-copy").cloneNode(true)
    const totalNewForm = document.getElementById('id_form-TOTAL_FORMS')
    const currentForms = document.getElementsByClassName("block")

    let totalForms = currentForms.length
    
    copyForm.setAttribute('class', 'block')
    copyForm.setAttribute('id', `form-${totalForms}`)

    const regex = new RegExp('__prefix__', 'g')
    copyForm.innerHTML = copyForm.innerHTML.replace(regex)

    totalNewForm.setAttribute('value', totalForms + 1)

    formCopyTarget.append(copyForm)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `action` attribute in your HTML. Also, I don't see the submit button anywhere.

```html
<form method="POST" id="form" action="{% url 'your-url-name-here' %}">
```